# Como setar e acessar sessão depois de usar session_name

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma `$_SESSION["id"]="123";`
e acesso ela direto assim:

```
echo $_SESSION["id"];
```

Se eu usar o

```
session_name(md5("seg".$_SERVER["REMODE_ADDR"].$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));
```

**como vou acessar ou setar a sessão?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você utilizar apenas o `session_name()` ele retornará o nome da sessão atual. Quando você cria um name para a `session_name($name)` ele irá sobrescrever o nome da sessão atual e retornará o antigo nome.

Então quando você dá um nome para a sessão:

```
session_name(md5("seg".$_SERVER["REMODE_ADDR"].$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));
```

E quer resgata-la. Basta fazer isso:

```
$nomeDaSessao = session_name();
```

Dá uma olhada no "[manuel](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-name.php)"

> O nome da sessão refere-se ao nome da sessão, que é usado em cookies e
> URLs (por exemplo, PHPSESSID). Ele deve conter apenas caracteres
> alfanuméricos; ele deve ser curto e descritivo (para usuários com
> avisos de cookie habilitados). Se name é informado, o nome da sessão
> atual é modificado para o novo valor.

**EDIT**

**pagina1.php**

```
// a variável ficará com o nome da antiga sessao PHPSESSID 
$sessao_antiga = session_name("teste"); // alterei o PHPSESSID para teste 

session_start(); // inicio a sessao

$session_name_new = session_name(); // recupero o nome da atual

echo "O nome da sessão é ".$session_name_new."<br>"; // mostro o nome da atual
echo "Mas o nome da sessão antes era ".$sessao_antiga."<br>"; // mostro o nome da antiga

$_SESSION['id'] = "123"; // abro uma sessão com o nome id

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ // verifico se existe a sessao
    echo "A sessão com a chave 'id' existe! O valor dela é ".$_SESSION['id']; // mostro uma msg
}
```

O exemplo acima vai retornar:

```
O nome da sessão é teste
Mas o nome da sessão antes era PHPSESSID
A sessão com a chave 'id' existe! O valor dela é 123
```

Repare que quando você altera o nome da sessão, você altera o cookie PHPSESSID, e vincula as outras sessões a este nome. É importante destacar que essa alteração tem que ser feita ANTES do `session_start()`.

Porém, para você recuperar essas chaves em cada script, você precisará alterar o nome da sessão também nas outras páginas. Assim:

**pagina2.php**

```
session_name("teste");

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    echo "A sessão 'id' Existe!";
}
```

O exemplo acima vai retornar:

**A sessão 'id' Existe!**

Comment: Obrigado Andrei

Comment: @RodrigoMarques não esquece de aprovar... =) Abraço!

Comment: Dúvida, ao usar md5 para setar uma nome para a sessão, pode haver algum problema se dois usuários tiverem o mesmo nome de sessão?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam neste caso, ACHO que não, pois ele está pegando o `$_SERVER["REMODE_ADDR"]`. Mas seria bom ele inserir um date também. E tem um salt ali com o "seg"

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam se dois usuários tiverem o mesmo nome da sessão, não será problema se ele não estiver gerenciando isso. Geralmente esse name é alterado para que você possa gerenciar isso por ter muitos usuários usando a MESMA aplicação por exemplo. Ai você pode derrubar as sessões dinamicamente.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam no caso dele é apenas para "segurança". Eu nem sei se isso amplia a segurança. Mas... Se não ampliar, não modifica nada. Apenas deixará um pouco mais lento.

Comment: então eu setaria assim $nomeDaSessao['id']='blablabla'; e acessaria assim echo $nomeDaSessao['id']; porque o nome da seção padrao é PHPSESSID e eu acesso com $_SESSION

Comment: @RodrigoMarques vou colocar um exemplo para vc entender.

Comment: @RodrigoMarques ficou mais claro? Qualquer coisa chama aqui...

Comment: pelo que entendi, indiferente do nome da seção vou sempre usar o $_SESSION['*'] para chamar ela, a unica diferença é que vou ter que setar o nome da sessão antes do session_start(); de todas as minhas paginas que usarem a sessão. isso?

Comment: existe algum pv aqui?

Comment: @RodrigoMarques exato. Se você não setar o nome, ele não irá encontrar a `SESSION['*']`.

Comment: @RodrigoMarques como assim.. pv???